# Select the following span jquery

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I have to loop through several of these `eachLocation` Div which holds various places and their addresses.

```
    $('.eachLocation').each(function(index) {
         var address=$(this).siblings().find('span.LocationAddress').text();
     });
```

I am not getting any value for address??? Am I doing something wrong?

```
<div class="eachLocation" >
            <div class="LocationCounter">1.</div>
            <div class="LocationInfo">
                <span class="LocationName">Kay Kay Center</span><br/> 
                <span class="LocationAddress">
                    1019 fairfax road, Bellevue, NE 68005
                </span><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do it this way

```
$('.eachLocation').each(function(index) {
    var address=$('span.LocationAddress', this).html();
});
```

this will work for sure...

Comment: +1 - In case others are missing it, Senad used the context parameter to filter. `$('selector', context)`. It is a very useful thing to know!

Comment: Can i use text() instead of html()? Is there any difference?

Comment: this is where you can look for your answer. http://api.jquery.com/text/ basically text() will return only text combined from all child elements, and html() will return html

Answer (score 2):

locationAddress is not a sibling of eachLocation. So don't use `siblings`

```
$('.eachLocation').each(function(index) {     
    var address=$(this).find('span.LocationAddress').text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head : Have you tried using `.html()` instead of `.text()`? [source](http://api.jquery.com/html/) Also I think you mean `.children` not `.siblings`

Answer (score 1):

If HTML, won't change then you can target the address directly:-

If span contains normal text

```
var address = $('.eachLocation div span.LocationAddress').text();
```

If span contains html

```
var address = $('.eachLocation div span.LocationAddress').html();
```

In other way,

```
$('.eachLocation span.LocationAddress').each(function() {
    var address = $(this).html();
});
```

​